# Angular: Using a sprite sheet with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sprite

So I have a sprite that is 107x3280

It is a collection of 107x80 thumbnails stacked vertically (41 thumbnails to be exact).

I am trying to display the thumbnail using the sprite method with `background-position`

```
<ul id="list" class="unstyled">
  <li id="listItem{{slide.slideIndex}}">
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background: url(resources/slides/thumbs.jpg) no-repeat;" ng-style="getSpriteStyle($index)"></span>
    <span class="listItemText">
      <b>{{slide.slideIndex + 1}}. </b>{{slide.title}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I created a function called getSpriteStyle($index) but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$scope.getSpriteStyle = function(id)
{
    log('background-position: 0 ' + (id * 80) + 'px;');
    return 'background-position: 0 ' + (id * 80) + 'px;';
}
```

The function traces out in the console perfectly:

```
background-position: 0 0px;
background-position: 0 80px
background-position: 0 160px;
background-position: 0 240px;
background-position: 0 320px;
// etc
```

Doing this seems to still only show the first thumbnail. It's like `ngStyle` isn't actually positioning anything. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I ran into an interesting problem. So my sprite is vertical and the thumbnails are in a specific order, top to bottom. I had to make the `(id * 80)` negative. I noticed the thumbnails were all backwards in the wrong order and setting that value negative put them in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngStyle from the docs:

Expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys.

You are returning a string from $scope.getSpriteStyle and not an object.

```
$scope.getSpriteStyle = function(id)
{
    log('background-position: 0 ' + (id * 80) + 'px;');
    return {"background-position": '0 ' +(id * 80) + 'px;'};
}
```

Comment: Changing it to an object with key value pairs didn't seem to make a difference :|

Comment: I figured it out. The fact I had a `no-repeat` on `style` was breaking it somehow. Solution is: `ng-style="{'background-position': getSpriteStyle($index)}"` and `$scope.getSpriteStyle = function(id){return '0 ' + (id * 80) + 'px';}`